# mysql select from table a where condition x and subselect

Tags: mysql, select

I want to count the amount of registries in table A to an specific amount of time determined at table B.

I am looking for the proper way of do something like this:

```
SELECT count(*) as total
from table_a as a
WHERE a.created >= '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND a.created <= (SELECT table_b.end WHERE table_b.id = 13)
```

Basically, table_b consists of 3 columns: an int primary key named 'id', a datetime named 'start', and an other datetime named 'end'. This is the way I have identified all the weeks of the current year.

Comment: you missed From clause in second select query...

Comment: thanks! I didn't expect to be that close to the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone need that, this is the proper way to do that:

```
SELECT count(*) as total
from table_a as a
WHERE a.created >= '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND a.created <= (SELECT table_b.`end` FROM table_b WHERE table_b.`id`=13)
```

Comment: Hm, it's *a way*. Not sure that it's *the proper way*!

Answer (score 1):

You could do typical join:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM table_a AS a 
JOIN table_b as b ON (a.created >= '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and a.created <= b.`end`)
WHERE b.id=13;
```

Given the description you probably want to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM table_a AS a 
JOIN table_b as b ON (a.created >= `start` and a.created <= `end`)
WHERE b.id=13;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(*) as total
from table_a as a
WHERE a.created >= '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND a.created <= (SELECT table_b.end from table_b WHERE table_b.id = 13)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use BETWEEN clause to achieve this,

```
SELECT count(*) as total
from table_a a
WHERE a.created BETWEEN '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND (SELECT table_b.`end` FROM table_b WHERE table_b.`id`=13)
```